# Как вносить изменения только в одну строчку TMemo?

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  chikl := strtoint(edit1.Text);

  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);

  for li := 1 to chikl do
    memo2.Lines.Add('send_photo_file(chat_id,' + memo1.Lines.Text + ')');

  memo2.Lines.SaveToFile('Mail.txt');
end;
```

почему то вместо одной строчки из мемо1 он добавляет все разом

Comment: не легче делать через seltext?

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `memo1.lines.text` используйте `memo1.lines[]` с соответствующим индексом.

Вот только есть сомнения, как соотносится `chikl`  с реальным количеством строк в меме